# Extracting text within frame tree in html

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml, python-3.5

I would like to scrape a frame within a website (https://www.harris.com/careers/jobs). THe Xpath for the location for the first listed job position is

```
/html/body/center/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/span
```

I am attempting to extract the text within the span using lxml library in Python. My code is currently as follows

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.harris.com/careers/jobs')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

location = tree.xpath('/html/body/center/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/span/text()')
```

Unfortunately the command

```
print(test)
```

yields the following

```
[]
```

I'm quite sure there's something wrong with the Xpath and that it can be improved to extract the text I need.

Comment: There is definitely something wrong if it does not work, also I don't see any job listings in the page you provided, I see an option to search for jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I will give working code for that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
try:
    driver.get("https://www.harris.com/careers/jobs")
    driver.switch_to.frame("frmJobs");
    time.sleep(5)
    #s = driver.find_element_by_id("searchbuttonBtn__a")
    s = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='submitbutton']")
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",s)
    print s.get_attribute("value")
    s.send_keys("\n")
    time.sleep(10)
    for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='listheadingbackground']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/a"):
        print a.get_attribute("href")
except Exception as e:
    print e
driver.quit()
```

Comment: appreciate it. Thanks